# GitLab - unable to push image created by one to another repository, both private

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I am experimenting with inter-repo communication on GitLab in terms of pushing/retrieving packages and images. I have setup a private group (so all projects inside are also private).

**REPO 1**

Here I build an image using Kaniko and push it both to the repo's own container registry as well as to the other. The CI pipeline config file is simple:

```
stages:
  - build


kaniko-image:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: ['']
  tags:
    - gitlab-org
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
      when: on_success
#      changes:
#        - .gitlab-ci.yml
#        - Dockerfile
  script:
    # https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/issues/687
    # PRO TIP: write the echo result locally to a file and use a JSON formatter to detect formatting errors
    - |
      export IMAGES_REGISTRY_URL=registry.gitlab.com/REPO2
      export IMAGES_TOKEN_NAME=IMAGES_REGISTRY
      export IMAGES_TOKEN_VALUE=$IMAGES_REGISTRY_TOKEN
      echo "{\"auths\":{\"${CI_REGISTRY}\":{\"auth\":\"$(printf "%s:%s" "${CI_REGISTRY_USER}" "${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')\"},\"auths\":{\"${IMAGES_REGISTRY_URL}\":{\"auth\":\"$(printf "%s:%s" "${CI_REGISTRY_USER}" "${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')\"}}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
      cat /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    
    - /kaniko/executor
       --context .
       --dockerfile Dockerfile
       --insecure
       --skip-tls-verify
       --skip-tls-verify-pull
       --insecure-pull
       --destination "${IMAGES_REGISTRY_URL}:kaniko-v0.1"
       --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:v0.1"
```

**REPO 2**

This repository currently serves only as a dumping ground for images from **REPO 1**. In the future I will add Kubernetes deployment. In the CI/CD settings I have whitelisted **REPO 1** to have access via `CI_JOB_TOKEN` to **REPO 2**:

[image: Repo 1 (where image is built) is whitelisted in Repo 2]

My CI job in **REPO 1** fails with

```
$ /kaniko/executor --context . --dockerfile Dockerfile --insecure --skip-tls-verify --skip-tls-verify-pull --insecure-pull --destination "${IMAGES_REGISTRY_URL}:kaniko-v0.1" --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:v0.1"
error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: checking push permission for "registry.gitlab.com/REPO2:kaniko-v0.1": POST https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/REPO2/blobs/uploads/: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:REPO2 ProjectPath: Type:repository] map[Action:push Class: Name:REPO2 ProjectPath: Type:repository]]
```

From my experience private repos mean trouble when it comes to inter-repo access. The only solution I have found so far is the following (source repo = **REPO 1**, destination repo = **REPO 2**):

1. Add access token to destination repo
2. Copy value of token and save as variable (masked) in source repo
3. Add variable with destination repo container registry URL  to source repo or `export` URL as variable inside CI job script in source repo
4. Use variables in CI job in source repo (e.g. `printf` their encoded values in an `auth` for the Kaniko JSON config or use an `auth` with `username` and `password` keys)

This works but only if you have yet again SaaS or self-hosted setup (this affects both project and group access tokens!). Plus it is too much fiddling. I am looking for an alternative solution that I can restrict only to the definition of the CI job in **REPO 1**

Group access tokens are a possibility, but only for SaaS and self-hosted, which is not an option for me since I'm using https://gitlab.com.